# How to hide other team member's calendar entries if I have them too?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, merge, duplicate

Since I'm displaying the calendars of other team members, I see appointments where more than one of them (including me or not) participate for *every* participant. Is there any way to visually merge those entries in the week display, or at least hide all but one of them?

To clarify, I use overlay mode due to the amount of calendars, and currently it looks like this:

[image: outlook calender, overlay mode, identical entries by different persons]

As you can see, some entries such as the brown and green one at the bottom left are identical except for being in two different (persons') calendars. I'd like these entries to show up merged into one item (e.g. only a green box with a brown border, or half green, half brown, or even only one color but with other entries from only green still showing up) to decrease clutter.

I wouldn't mind using an add-on if Outlook doesn't natively support this.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot or something showing the problem? I'm having a hard time understanding the issue and what you're trying to accomplish, so others may as well. It could be the wording perhap but a screen shot may clarify.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE Good point, added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Outlook user myself and given the information i found the following, hope it helps :

*Overlay Mode and Side-by-Side Calendars*

Side-by-Side Calendars is the feature which lets you select multiple Calendars when you are in the Calendar Navigation (CTRL+2) simply by clicking the checkbox in front of the Calendar.

Overlay Mode is the feature where you can actually place these Calendar “on top of each other” to create a aggregated view which looks like a single Calendar.

You can find the feature in the following location:

```
Outlook 2007
View-> View in Overlay Mode
Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016
tab View-> option group: Arrangement-> button: Overlay
```

Another way to do this would be to press the arrow icon tab is shown at the top of each Calendar tab (next to the name). This allows you to combine some Calendars and to view others side-by-side.

*Merge into one calendar*

If you really want to merge the calendars, it’s easy – use a list view then drag the items to the other folder. Or use the Move to folder command. It doesn’t matter which type of Outlook folder you are using, the method is the same for all folders.

> Begin by selecting the folder you want to stop using. If its a calendar folder, switch to a list view, such as All Appointments or By Category. In Outlook 2010, it’s called List view. In Contacts, use Phone list view.
>   Click on one item, the press Ctrl+A to select all.
>   Use the Move to folder (or Copy to folder) command or drag the items to the folder you want to move the items to.

Comment: Thanks, my question wasn't as fleshed out as I thought it was... I am already using overlay mode, but as some entries are in multiple (other persons') calendars (which I can therefore not actually merge as you described in the second half of your answer) I'd like them to still show only once, maybe with some other visual clue (e.g. colored bars) to indicate the calendars involved...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a common color to your Team/Group calendar

- Select your Team calendar on left pane
- De-select your calendar
- Go to Ribbon & find color option
- Pick a color of your choice and apply to the calendars which obstruct you in overlay view

  [image]

You cannot merge the entries into one

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you suggest basically introducing a "not me" color? That seems rather counter-productive, not only does this not solve my original problem (I can spot my own entries immediately, but I'd like multi-participant entries to be less redundant), but then I couldn't even see to whom a non-common entry belongs.

Comment: Oh well, unless another answer shows up, I'll probably award the bounty to this answer for creativity ;)

Comment: In the spirit of fairness, I've placed a [bounty](http://superuser.com/questions/1009618) myself

Comment: What goes around comes around :D Incidentally, a question interesting me as well...

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, there is no way to hide duplicate calendar items on multiple/shared calendars.  The only real option would be to delete from a calendar.

For example.  If there is a "Team" calendar, and an appt. is made on that calendar and people from the team are invited, you would receive an email with the invite.  If you accept the invite, it's going to add the appt. to your calendar, as well as the original on the team calendar.  If you have both calendars set in overlay mode, both items will show up (typically side by side).  Since the original meeting is on the shared calendar, you could delete the one on your calendar.  Or, vice versa.

Setting the color of the calendars to be the same may help them to blend, but as you pointed out, it will not remove them from your calendar.  Plus, it may make it difficult for your appointments to actually stand out from the others when needed.

Hope that helps, or at least helps to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

OK, This is an older one, but I was looking for a solution to this problem, and found this question. some of the comments etc here gave me enough to get a solution.

1. On the shared calendar, mark all of the appointments that you also have in your own calendar with one of the colour categories. (I chose purple, as it's for 'Teams')
2. Open the current view settings, and click filter
3. Goto the 'advanced' tab and then click 'define more criteria'
4. Set the criteria to 'Categories' (which for me was under 'frequently used'), 'Doesn't contain' and finally 'Purple Category'. (if you chose a different category, use that instead)
5. click 'OK' on the filter window, and the view settings window. Your shared appointments should disappear, allowing you to use the overlay mode without the duplication.